# Send email of failed test cases details using allure report

Tags: email, jenkins-plugins, html-email, allure

I want to know if there is a way of sending an email which will contain the details of failed test cases using allure report? We are using jenkins for publishing allure report but would need to send failure details over email.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article: https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/337386/ they are gonna make a feature of creating PDF and CSV reports, yet they just plan it and haven't don't it for now.

**So for now Allure doesn't allow you to send their report via email**. But I guess you can use any other reports.

Comment: which report provides this feature then? Also one thought - Allure reports generates CSV and Json file of report. Can we write some code to read the values from CSV or json and then putting them in email? If you know how to do it, could you please let me know?